# in python code use variables instead of values for html font attributes

Tags: html, variables, fonts, attributes, python-3.6

Actually i have to store in my python3 program data as output in html file,with this i want to let user set html font attributes, or we can say i want to store html font attributes first in variables and then use those variables in html's font attributes. for example this is the usual way to set font attributes in html:

```
<html>
<body>

<p><font face="verdana" color="green" size="3">This is some text!</font></p>

</body>
</html>
```

but i want something like this:

```
font_face = "verdana"
font_color = "green"
font_size = 3

<html>
<body>

<p><font face="font_face" color="font_color" size="font_size">This is some text!</font></p>

</body>
</html>
```

I googled a lot to find its solution but not able to find, now i am asking here hoping some one will give its solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I would recommend using a templating framework like `jinja2` if you're trying to render html.

But if you want to output text as html and to insert values into it...it would probably look something like:

```
font_face = "verdana"
font_color = "green"
font_size = 3

html = """
<html>
<body>

<p><font face="{font_face}" color="{font_color}" size="{font_size}">This is some text!</font></p>

</body>
</html>
""".format(font_face=font_face, font_color=font_color, font_size=font_size)
```

This will give you a string that will contain the html you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. Your solution and code did the job.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use templates with python library, but, string format looks better and you don't need an import to use them
it's funny, i've been working on Django all day long and forgot about .format()

```
from string import Template

font_face = "verdana"
font_color = "green"
font_size = 3

font = Template('<p><font face="${font_face}" color="${font_color}" size="${font_size}">This is some text!</font></p>')
font.substitute(font_face=font_face, font_color=font_color, font_size=font_size)
```